# Windows Batch file - Delete with Y/N prompt and not allow wild cards

Tags: batch-file

I don't think this is a duplicate question (much to my surprise). I'm not a fan of using batch files and I can count on 1 hand the number of times I've had to create one.

I'm trying to create a batch file for deleting 1 file at a time, **without** wild cards. If the file name doesn't exist, then the batch file should terminate.

My errant batch file:

```
 @echo off
set /p image="Enter file name (e.g. car.jpg):"
set fullFileName=C:\testimages\%image%

IF EXIST "%fullFileName%" (
    ECHO[
    del /P /F "%fullFileName%" 
) ELSE (
    ECHO File %fullFileName% doesn't exist
)

pause
```

Correct:

```
Enter file name (e.g. car.jpg):car.jpg

C:\testimages\car.jpg, Delete (Y/N)?
```

Correct:

```
Enter file name (e.g. car.jpg):plane.jpg
File C:\testimages\plane.jpg doesn't exist
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I want to disallow any wild cards. Such as the following:

```
Enter file name (e.g. car.jpg):*

C:\testimages\bus.jpg, Delete (Y/N)? n
C:\testimages\car.jpg, Delete (Y/N)? n
C:\testimages\truck.jpg, Delete (Y/N)? n
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: What should happen if the user does enter a wildcard?

Comment: Batch file should terminate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you want to disallow the user entering in * or ?.  There are other undocumented wildcards as well though.

```
@echo on

:loop
cls
set /p "image=Enter file name (e.g. car.jpg):"

(echo "%image%"|findstr /L "* ? < > ^" >nul 2>&1) && GOTO :EOF

set "fullFileName=C:\testimages\%image%"

IF EXIST "%fullFileName%" (
    ECHO[
    ECHO del /P /F "%fullFileName%" 
) ELSE (
    ECHO File "%fullFileName%" doesn't exist
)
endlocal
pause
```

There are probably more robust ways to check for input validation.  I am sure this could be broken in some form.

Comment: also `for /F "tokens=1* delims=?*" %%A in ("%image%") do if "%%B" NEQ "" goto :EOF`

Comment: @elzooilogico, that does not work in all instances.  I was actually doing a FOR /F with my first set of code.

Comment: didn't test all cases. I have never user the `/L` switch of `findstr`. Like it.

Comment: @elzooilogico, besides for the undocumented wildcards, your approach works in case you replace `%image%` by `_%image%_`...

Comment: @aschipfl, cannot see difference, can you provide an example? BTW, [Dir undocumented wildcards](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6207)

Comment: The `for /F` approach fails in case wildcards appear only at the beginning and/or at the end; adding a "normal" character like `_` at the beginning and at the end makes the wildcards appear *inside* of the string, so the second token (`%%B`) will never appear empty as soon as a wildcard occurs...

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using the `for /F` command:

```bat
set "image=" & set /P image="Enter file name: "
for /F tokens^=1*^ delims^=?*^<^>^" %%A in ("_%image%_") do set "TEST=%%B"
if defined TEST echo There are wild-cards!
```

If at least one wild-card is present in `%image%`, `%%B` and hence `TEST` are not empty. The `_` characters are prepended and appended for the approach not to fail in case wild-cards are only present at the beginning and/or at the end of `%image%`.

---

This is another option using a standard `for` loop:

```bat
set "image=" & set /P image="Enter file name: " & set "FLAG=#"
for %%A in ("%image%") do if /I "%image%"=="%%~nxA" (set "FLAG=") else goto :QUIT
:QUIT
if defined FLAG echo There are wild-cards!
```

If at least one wild-card is present in `%image%`, the `for` loop resolves it by accessing the file system and returning the matching items (zero or more); this means that the original string `%image%` does not equal any of the iterated items, so the `if` query fails; the `goto` is there to avoid any more iterations, hence to break the loop; if no items match, the loop does not iterate at all. If no wild-cards are present in `%image%`, the `for` loop iterates once only over the original string, hence the `if` condition is fulfilled and variable `FLAG` is cleared.